Can faulty cpu fan cause boot issues
I have Gigabyte H110M-S2 motherboard which supports Intel 6th and 7th generation processors.
I have:

Intel i3 - 6100 processor.
And 8GB of RAM
And I am using stock cooler as CPU cooler and it has been running for maybe 5-6 years.

And the fan struggles to spin at start. But once it picks up it's going great (I think its bearing must have gone a bit) but sometimes it works great and doesn't struggle to start.
But when it does struggle to start the PC doesn't post it's just turn on and turns off again and again and again.
Does this cause the issue?

It COULD be the cause of the issue. Systems have been able to read the performance of their critical fans for a long time, and have had some form of protection connected to that. In my experience the computers usually report a fan failure visually on the screen when this happens. The computer shutting off and turning back on repeatedly may be how your computer hardware handles this fault condition. You'll be able to confirm whether this is the cause by replacing your CPU fan.

yes, most motherboards (and their firmware) check to make sure power is being drawn through the CPU fan headers, and will choose not to boot if there is an issue. some firmwares allow you to turn that feature off, to allow boot, but others do not. seriously, just replace the fan or the whole heatsink.

Yes, in most consumer computers a failing or faulty CPU fan will prevent the computer booting. This is done to preserve the hardware, preventing further damage. A fan is cheap and easy to replace, but running a computer without a necessary fan like the CPU fan WILL cause much more extensive and expensive damage, so this is the normal behavior.
However, these could also be SYMPTOMS of a different issue, and you would need to follow normal hardware diagnostic processes if replacing the fan does not resolve this.
The reason I gave a comment and did not answer several days ago is because you have not given sufficient information to 100% confirm the core issue is the CPU fan. But, it is a good-enough place to start your repair efforts, because it is an inexpensive and relatively easy fix, and those factors usually determine initial hardware repair steps.
